# Struct pointer passed into function in C does not work even after forward declaration

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm new to C and am learning linked lists. I am using Code Blocks IDE on Linux Mint with a GCC compiler. I am trying to pass in a struct pointer to a function that can help me traverse the the linked list. Here is my present code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void gothru(struct node * Root);

struct node {
    int data; //data in current node
    struct node * next; //pointer to the next node
};

void gothru(struct node * Root){
    struct node * conductor; //this pointer will be used to traverse the linked list
    conductor = Root; //conductor will start at the Node

    /* Conductor traverses through the linked list */
    if(conductor != NULL){
        while(conductor->next != NULL){
            printf("%d->",conductor->data);
            conductor = conductor->next; /*if current position of conductor is not pointing to
                                           end of linked list, then go to the next node */
        }
        printf("%d->",conductor->data);
    }

    printf("\n");

    if (conductor == NULL){
        printf("Out of memory!");
    }

    free(conductor);
}

int main()
{
    struct node * root; //first node

    root = malloc(sizeof(*root)); //allocate some memory to the root node

    root->next = NULL; //set the next node of root to a null/dummy pointer
    root->data = 12; //data at first node (root) is 12

    gothru(root); //traverse linked list


    return 0;
}
```

Now, I have forward declared my function at the top with the exact same format as when the function is first initialized. But still, I'm getting the following error:

> |11|error: conflicting types for ‘gothru’

I have tried changing the argument for my "gothru" function to simple variables in which case it works. But the minute I change back to a pointer to the struct, it gives me this error.

Previous answers in Stackoverflow say that we need to forward declare our functions to clear this error. I did exactly that, but it still does not work. Any solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The forward declaration of the `gothru` function contains the structure type as one of the parameter, so, you need to move the forward declaration for `gothru` after the structure definition.

Otherwise, the function argument (type) is not known in the forward declaration time.

Something like

```
struct node {
    int data; //data in current node
    struct node * next; //pointer to the next node
};

void gothru(struct node * Root);  // struct node is known to compiler now
```

should solve the problem.

Comment: in that case you don't even need to provide it, since it immediately follows.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Right, but does no harm, either. :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh sure. I'm sure having seen this as a duplicate somewhere (NMDV BTW)

Answer (score 1):

Using gcc we get this if we try to compile your code:

```
vagrant@dev-box:~/tests$ gcc test.c
test.c:4:20: warning: ‘struct node’ declared inside parameter list [enabled by default]
 void gothru(struct node * Root);
                    ^
test.c:4:20: warning: its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is probably not what you want [enabled by default]
test.c:11:6: error: conflicting types for ‘gothru’
 void gothru(struct node * Root){
      ^
test.c:4:6: note: previous declaration of ‘gothru’ was here
 void gothru(struct node * Root);
      ^
```

The warning that is shown first is crucial to understanding what is going on here. Here, `struct node` is first declared inside the function prototype and it's scope is just that line. But it declares the function. Now after defining the `struct node` you encounter the function definition but in this line `struct node` means something different from the local `struct node` encountered in first prototype. And that's why you are getting a conflicting type for the function.

The solution is as already pointed by @SouravGhosh's answer, i.e. to move the structure definition before the function prototype.